# How to initialize an array of objects from response data in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a server side script that collects sensor data into a database with multi-threading. On the front-end I have a very simple angular page, where I would like to display these data in graphs. The plan is that I get the active modules that are measuring sensor information on the server side. An example response for that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "CPU Usage",
    "frequency": 5,
    "unit": "%"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Memory Usage",
    "frequency": 4,
    "unit": "GB"
}
]
```

Then I would like to create two graphs that I can update over the time. This is the code I'm trying to use to set up the graphs:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  public charts: [];
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private dataService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpClient.get<any>(this.dataService.baseUrl + '/measurable/active').subscribe({
      next: data => {
        console.debug(data);
        data.forEach(function (item, charts) {
          // let charts = [];
          document.getElementById('charts').innerHTML
            += '<label>' + item.name + '(' + item.unit + ')' + '</label>'
            + '<canvas id="chart' + item.id + '" style="width:100%; height:200px" width="1262" height="200"></canvas>';

          let newCharts = new SmoothieChart();
          newCharts.streamTo(document.getElementById('chart' + item.id));

          charts.push(newCharts);
        });
      },
      error: error => {
        console.error('Could not load any measurable', error.message);
      }
    })
    console.debug(this.charts);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with front-end technologies, so I don't really know how should I do it correctly to make it work. Can someone help me with it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are you expecting the `console.log(this.charts)` to log the charts? This won't work
   because the http request is a asynchronous call. so the request is initiated and browser moves to execute next statement
2. That means after initiating the backend request the browser moves to `console.log(this.charts)` statement. the code inside subscribe runs after http request is complete
3. Use can see this in action by adding break points
4. Now add the `console.log(this.charts)` after `forEach` loop ends inside subscription.
5. Using innerHtml, queryselecting is not a recommended thing in angular. You can do the same thing in a easier way using angular interpolation `{{}}`. For this save the data from service to a public property in class and use it in html.
6. It is not a recommended way to call a http service from a component. Move the call to backend api to a service and call the service from the component